# How do I subscribe to podcast in iTunes remotely? 

Tags: itunes, ipod, windows, iphone

I have an iPhone 3Gs that is synchronized with my home PC (Windows Vista).

But I spend most of the day at work (unsurprisingly), I don't have iTunes on my work PC and I never connect my iPhone to it.

Often, while at work, I see a link to a podcast that I want to listen to later - but I can't subscribe to it on the spot (because I'm not near my iTunes PC)

What I want is to subscribe to the podcast on my work PC, over the web (without installing iTunes) and have the podcast waiting for me in iTunes on my home PC.

Is that possible? I can't find anything like this in iTunes and can't find any 3rd party application or service that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know of a software that can do that automatically, however you have two choices:

1) If you want the podcast to be downloaded and ready, you will have to remote control your home PC and do it normally as if you were sitting in front of your computer. (Either through VNC or Windows Remote Connection)

2) If you don’t mind doing it when you get to your home, you can use a service like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) and have a text file with the URLs. Since Dropbox will sync automatically, you can open the file when you get home and the urls will be there. Or use a service like [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com) to save the URLs that will be ready when you get home to be added to your home iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an app like [Instacast](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instacast/id420368235?mt=8). Instacast allows you to manage and listen to podcasts within the app, all without using iTunes. It features its own player, 2x playback mode, bi-directional skipping and AirPlay support.

[image: Instacast player]
[image: Instacast downloading podcast]

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post an Applescript to handle subscriptions over mail then I realized you said you were using a PC…

I would go with using something like Instapaper or even just emailing the iTunes link to yourself, then simply click the links when you get home.

Comment: Not an answer, but comment to ghoppe (no comment option for some reason) but i think it would be useful for others to post that script.